# What is the role of sas.exe file

Tags: sas

When I run the sas.exe, does it start the SAS Object Spawner or the SAS Application Server?

Also, let us say I write a stored process on SAS enterprise guide and try to run it. When I click 'Run', will it call sas.exe in the background if not running already?

Answer (score 1):

No, SAS.exe is the underlying SAS engine.  The Object Spawner runs sas.exe.  To that end, a Stored Process server has an Object Spawner behind it.  When you run a Stored Process, it runs on the server in a sas.exe process.  The Stored Process server maintains a pool of server processes.  It will run your process in a currently spawned sas.exe and only start a new sas.exe process if it needs it.